# Add a character before another in bash

Tags: bash

I have a string Which is a url like

```
http://blabla.com/blob.php?HERE
```

I wanted to Add a \ backslash before HERE so it looks

```
blob.php?\HERE
```

Also would it be possibile to make it a function like a pass the url and automatically it adds the \

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post what you already tried?

Comment: Havent tried anything yet..  Was searching online for a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
add_slash() {
    echo "$1" | sed 's/\(.*php?\)/\1\\/' 
}

s="http://blabla.com/blob.php?HERE"

add_slash $s
```

If you launch this script will return
`http://blabla.com/blob.php?\HERE`

Answer (score 0):

```
passchar() {
    echo ${1/HERE/\\HERE}
}

passchar "http://blabla.com/blob.php?HERE"
```

Comment: Thats not working.  It truncated the string and doesnt show the last part

Comment: Try it within quotes: `echo "${1/HERE/\\HERE}"`

Comment: Thanks its working great!!  Also now..  Would it be possibile to assign a variable to the new output and run a command with it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$ add_a_char() { printf '%s\n' "${1%"$2"}\\$2"; }

$ add_a_char "http://blabla.com/blob.php?HERE" "HERE"
http://blabla.com/blob.php?\HERE
```